# Turning a Double into color ints in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, colormap

I'm working with an image in android studio. To make it simple let's say it only has 9 pixels. The values of the pixel are held in a double matrix in, lets say its something I like this:

```
double[][] matrix = {{-0.5, -0.4, -0.3},
                     {-0.1, -0.9, -0.4},
                     {-0.5, -0.6, -0.9}}
```

I want to turn each of those doubles into a color int so I can put them into an image pixel by pixel. (In Matlab you'd use something like `colormap('jet')`).

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(length, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                for(int i = 0; i< length ; i++ ){
                    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++){
                        //Convert number in matrix to color from blue to red
                        int color;

                        //Make correlating pixel that color
                        bitmap.setPixel(i,j, color);
                    }
                }
```

I have tried using the Scichart SDK but the license is too expensive.
I also tried the Mines package but it depends on Java AWT which is not available in android studio

I can't find anything on the documentation.

Comment: You need to convert the color values from the input format to the output format. The output format is RGB, with 1 byte for R, G and B.
In what format are your input values?

Comment: My input values are just doubles.

Comment: yes, but what do the values represent? YUV? RGB? HSV? In what ranges?In order to make a meaningful conversion, you need to know what these values represent.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to map a value to a color by using one of the methods in `Color` class.

For example, using `Color.HSVToColor` and passing your value in as the "hue" will give you a rainbow color palette. The appropriate mapping will depend on what range the values in your matrix can take. If they are in the range -1 to +1, this will work for you:

```
float hue = (float) (matrix[i][j] + 1) * 180;
float[] hsv = { hue, 1f, 1f };
int color = Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
```

Comment: This is a good start. What do I do if my values are in a much closer range? When I tried running that I got the same color for every pixel.

Comment: Then you need to find a way to map the range where they are to the range expected by the color function. For the hue component of HSVToColor, the range is 0 to 360.